# Move one task item to another task

Tags: office-365, custom-list, tasks, move

I was curious if there is a simple way to move an item in one task to another task.  Example: We would have a task list called Requests.  Once an item in that list is approved we would move that item from Requests to the appropriate task like Production or Printing, etc...

What is the best way to go about that?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Can't think of any way in which you could move a task from one library to another, but a generic solution would be to close your "Request" task once its specifics are defined (such as that it should be assigned to "Printing") and based on a workflow create a new task in the "Printing" task list.

Can't think of any elegant way though!

Answer (score 0):

"WORKFLOWS" should be answer in your case. You can build one using SharePoint Designer or go for third party workflows using Nintex or K2 Which help building wfs in browser quick time.